# Phaser 3: Starting a scene (stopping all other running scenes) from the global "game" object

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

As the title says.. Is there a way to stop all running scenes when starting a scene from the "game" object?

For now, when I call `game.scene.start(...)` from outside a Scene object, nothing happens. My current solution is to keep a global variable pointing to the latest started Scene (In all my scenes, I reset that global variable in the `create()` function with something like `currentScene = this;`) So when I want to start a new Scene I call `currentScene.scene.start(...)`. But obviously that's not reliable because I could forget to reset my global variable (`currentScene`) in all my scenes, etc...

**EDIT:**

To clarifiy what I'm trying to acheive: I'm making a small multiplayer game with a couple scenes and a few GameObjects. I've a "socket" module that handles all traffic between the client and the server (I'm using socket.io). I would want to do something like:

```
this.socket.on('game_end', (data) => {
    // Server decides when the game stops and sends an event to all clients.
    // Here I need to stop the currently running scene (i.e. SceneInGame)
    // and show the "game finished / results" scene.
    this.game.scene.start('SceneGameEnd');
    // ^ That doesn't work. SceneInGame keeps playing and SceneGameEnd doesn't start
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You really shouldn't use `game.scene` at all in Phaser 3 (indeed, this won't even work as of Phaser 3.50.0). Scene operations should go via the `ScenePlugin`, which is accessible as `this.scene` from within any Scene. I.e. `this.scene.start('otherScene')` will *stop* the current Scene, then start the given one, in order, at the next game step. Where-as `game.scene.start` just blasts on through with no care to the game step or what's calling it.

There is no way to 'stop all running scenes' however, but then unless you have started *multiple* Scenes (via `launch` or a similar method), then there won't actually be any other running scenes. Show some actual code, then we can give a more targeted response.

Comment: Hello Richard, is there any method in Phaser 3 similar to game.state.getCurrentState  of Phaser 2?

Comment: "There are no states in phaser 3, they have been replaced with much better Scene system. Scenes are better than states."

Answer (score 1):

There's a way I was able to do this, that at least works with Phaser 3.55 by accessing the current scene manually and starting the new scene from there.

For example: `game.scene.keys.myCurrentScene.scene.start('SceneGameEnd')`
This will effectively call the `this.scene` of `myCurrentScene` and replace that scene by starting `SceneGameEnd`

Where `myCurrentScene` would be the key of the current running scene.
You can see the scene key at `game.scene.keys` property where all scenes are listed by key name.
However, this would only work if you know what's the key of the current running scene.
Probably there's a way to get the current running scene but I can't answer that one.

There is however a more of a brute force workaround if you don't know the key of the current running scene. You could run a loop through all scenes, regardless if it is running or not, from the array of `game.scene.scenes` and call `scene.stop` on all scenes and then run just the one you need.

For example:

```js
// Stop all scenes
game.scenes.forEach((scene) => {
  const key = scene.scene.key; // This is not a typo, the scene here is more like a "game" object, so the scene actually is under the "scene" property.
  game.scene.stop(key);
})
// After stopping all scenes, then you can start only the scene you need
game.scene.start('SceneGameEnd');
```